# Chrome extension "Speed Dial 2" does not work in incognito mode -- why?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, private-browsing

I installed the chrome extension `Speed Dial 2`. Although I ticked the checkbox "**Allow in incognito**" under `chrome://chrome/extensions`, but it does not work (works in normal mode). When a new tab is opened, the standard

"**`You are in incognito mode bla bla ...`**" is displayed.

If I manually enter the url

`chrome-extension://jpfpebmajhhopeonhlcgidhclcccjcik/newtab.html`

it does not work either (This works in NON-incognito mode!)

Thank you in advance for any suggestions how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

**To enable ANY chrome extension in incognito mode:**

1. Install the extension via the chrome store
2. Copy the extension to some other place: `cp -r ~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/jpfpebmajhhopeonhlcgidhclcccjcik/1.6.0.9_0 ~`
3. Go to the location of the copy: `cd ~/1.6.0.9_0`
4. Change **manifest.json**: `...
   ,"incognito": "split"}`
5. Go to `chrome://chrome/extensions`, check `Developer mode`, uninstall the extension via clicking the trash bin, click `Load unpacked extension...` and select `~/1.6.0.9_0`, check `Allow in incognito`

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [Speed Dial 2 page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jpfpebmajhhopeonhlcgidhclcccjcik?hl=en-US) has:

> Speed dial 2 is fast and clean extension for your favorite pages and quick access to your apps, bookmarks and browsing history.

and

> Speedial2 keeps track of your daily routines and remembers which pages you visit in the morning, afternoon, evening and night. These are afterwards highlighted to distinct pages you often visit at the current part of a day.

I would imagine that these features are expressly what are excluded when one chooses the incognito mode. In other words, the Speed Dial 2 features are contrary to what the incognito mode achieves.

Comment: The main feature of any speed dial is to visualise bookmarks in form of clickable thumbnails. I do not see why this should not be used in incognito mode. I use incognito mode by default, because chromium does not keep track of history and cookies in incognito mode. This way I do not have to bother with installing extensions to clear history etc ...

Comment: But this particular speed dial does more according to the quotes I found on the page. It's not just about bookmarks. It specifically tries to record history. And the new tab page is based not just on bookmarks but their frequency of use which implies recording visits to pages. Again incompatible with incognito mode.